# Inject js code in webview before showing page

Tags: java, android, webview

So, i want to inject some js code in the page, and i'm now i'm using this code:

```
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                        view.evaluateJavascript(jsCommand, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

But it's working like firstly page loaded and after that it show's injection. Of course i know why its happens, cause it's method is `onPageFinished`. But how i can when clicking on url into webview, like freeze webview, load url, and only after injection show page?